# Compare 2 Arrays and get matching items

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a multidimensional array that is displayed to users in a table, where they can select items by a checkbox.

When they've checked their items and submit, I've now got an array of id values that correspond to the myid key of the original sub arrays.

How can I search the original array and create a new array of only the matching selected items?

```
Array ( 
[0] => Array ( 
[myid] => 22 
[Price] => Some price
[Title] => Some text
 ) 
[1] => Array ( 
[myid] => 36 
[Price] => Some price
[Title] => Some text
 ) 
)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Something like array_intersect()?
  http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple way but can be optimized

```
<?php
$submittedVaule = array('12','14');
$subArray = array(0 => array('myid' => 12,'price' => '100','title' => 'test1'),1 => array('myid' => 13,'price' => '100','title' => 'test2'),2 => array('myid' => 14,'price' => '100','title' => 'test3'));

$finalarray = array();
foreach($subArray as $key=>$value){

   if(in_array($value['myid'], $submittedVaule )) {

    $finalarray[]=$subArray[$key];
   }
}

print_r($finalarray);
?>
```